# Cell width is increasing after click in react data grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Iam using react data grid component where it is working correctly in sandbox and when I tried locally cell size is increasing
My code in sand box https://codesandbox.io/embed/5vy2q8owj4?codemirror=1
Attached screenshot is my issue[image: cell width is overlapping into another cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boTJw.png)have you tried to add bootstrap 3.3.7 for UI component styles in index.html in public directory of your project.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Could you please explain how to add ? Or any sample ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">

Comment: add these cdn in <head> tag of your index.html file inside public directory and the whole head tag should look like <head> ....... the defualt code ..... then cdn before <title > tag

Comment: Adding this in css also helps * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}